# Python code overwrites previous date and time data in excel with date and time from most recent submission

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

I am very new to Python.

My code opens a data entry GUI then writes the inputs to an excel file when the submit button is clicked. However, when the submit button is clicked the current date and time overwrites any previous submissions to be the current date and time as well.

I want the code to log the date and time of submission without changing any previous logs. Date and Time are the only two fields that this happens to.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import time

today = date.today()
now = datetime.now().time()
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())

def submit_fields():
    path = 'good.xlsx'
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
    SeriesA = df1['Date']
    SeriesB = df1['Time']
    SeriesC = df1['Operator']
    SeriesD = df1['CNC']
    SeriesE = df1['Work Order']
    SeriesF = df1['Company']
    SeriesG = df1['Part']
    SeriesH = df1['Defect Qty']
    SeriesI = df1['Code']
    SeriesJ = df1['Outcome']
    SeriesK = df1['Good Qty']

    A = pd.Series(entry1.get())
    B = pd.Series(entry2.get())
    C = pd.Series(entry3.get())
    D = pd.Series(entry4.get())
    E = pd.Series(entry5.get())
    F = pd.Series(entry6.get())
    G = pd.Series(entry7.get())
    H = pd.Series(entry8.get())
    I = pd.Series(entry9.get())
    J = pd.Series(entry10.get())
    K = pd.Series(entry11.get())

    SeriesA = str(today)
    SeriesB = str(now)
    SeriesC = SeriesC.append(C)
    SeriesD = SeriesD.append(D)
    SeriesE = SeriesE.append(E)
    SeriesF = SeriesF.append(F)
    SeriesG = SeriesG.append(G)
    SeriesH = SeriesH.append(H)
    SeriesI = SeriesI.append(I)
    SeriesJ = SeriesJ.append(J)
    SeriesK = SeriesK.append(K)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":SeriesA, "Time":SeriesB, "Operator":SeriesC,"CNC":SeriesD, "Work Order":SeriesE,
                        "Company":SeriesF, "Part":SeriesG, "Defect Qty":SeriesH, "Code":SeriesI, "Outcome":SeriesJ,
                        "Good Qty":SeriesJ})
    df2.to_excel(path, index=False)

    entry3.delete(0, END)
    entry4.delete(0, END)
    entry5.delete(0, END)
    entry6.delete(0, END)
    entry7.delete(0, END)
    entry8.delete(0, END)
    entry9.delete(0, END)
    entry10.delete(0, END)
    entry11.delete(0, END)

########TOP LABEL#####################################1
master = Tk()

master.title("test")

lbl = Label(master, text="Hello")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
########TOP LABEL#####################################2

master.geometry('500x500')

Label(master, text="Date").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text=today).grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(master, text="Time").grid(row=1)

##########################################CLOCK###########################1
label = Label(master)
label.grid(row =1, column=1)
def digitalclock():
   text_input = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
   label.config(text=text_input)
   label.after(200, digitalclock)
digitalclock()
##########################################CLOCK###########################2

Label(master, text="Operator").grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="CNC").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="Work Order").grid(row=4)
Label(master, text="Company").grid(row=5)
Label(master, text="Part").grid(row=6)
Label(master, text="Defect Qty").grid(row=7)
Label(master, text="Code").grid(row=8)
Label(master, text="Outcome").grid(row=9)
Label(master, text="Good Qty").grid(row=10)

entry1 = Entry(master)
entry2 = Entry(master)
entry3 = Entry(master)
entry4 = Entry(master)
entry5 = Entry(master)
entry6 = Entry(master)
entry7 = Entry(master)
entry8 = Entry(master)
entry9 = Entry(master)
entry10 = Entry(master)
entry11 = Entry(master)
entry12 = Entry(master)

entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=4)
entry4.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=4)
entry5.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=4)
entry6.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=4)
entry7.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=4)
entry8.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=4)
entry9.grid(row=8, column=1, pady=4)
entry10.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=4)
entry11.grid(row=10, column=1, pady=4)

Button(master, text='Submit', command=submit_fields).grid(row=12,column=1, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the values instead of appending them - note that both `entry1` and `entry2` contains empty strings:

```python
    A = pd.Series(str(today))
    B = pd.Series(str(now))
    # ...
    SeriesA = SeriesA.append(A)
    SeriesB = SeriesB.append(B)
```